# Apache: “AuthType not set!” 500 Error

Tags: apache, apache-config

It's been a while since I used the Apache httpd web server in windows.
when I try to request localhost/index.html, I get a 500 error and I see this in the error log:

> [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /

This line in my httpd.conf may be involved.

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

my apache version is 2.2

OS : windows 7
how do I solve this 500 error?

Comment: what does apache error.log say about this?

Comment: [Tue May 31 22:44:45 2016] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the error message as it wasn't formatted properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the line `Require all granted`.

`Allow from all` in version <2.4 is equivalent to `Require all granted` for 2.4+.

Comment: when i remove the line as you said and restart apache, when i see the index.php ,it's change to download the page

Comment: @stefansaye, so you are not getting the 500 error anymore but the index.php is not working as expected?

Comment: Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them

Comment: the answer is centos,

Comment: @stefansaye, sorry, your comment is incomplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113430/discussion-between-stefansaye-and-silentmonk).

Comment: i have tried it , the same problem "Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them"